# Removing DC offset in MATLAB

Tags: dc, signal, matlab, demodulation, dc-offset

My teacher has a demodulated signal and he removed the DC offset with this one line of code in MATLAB:

`y_dc = y - mean(y)`

Can someone please explain how this line of code removes the DC offset?

Comment: the mean value is the DC value!

Answer (score 1):

The DC offset *is* the mean. Any non-DC (i.e. AC) components will have zero mean, while contributing to fluctuation around the mean, when the signal is long enough. (if the signal is very short, then a *partial* cycle of a sinusoidal component at some frequency may have a non-zero average)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite-length signal (`y` in your teacher's example), then *by definition* the DC component to that signal is it's average value.  In Matlab, that average value is `mean(y)`.

The concept of DC comes from frequency analysis, where a signal is a linear combination of signals at various frequencies.  That "linear" part means that if you know a signal's DC component, you can eliminate it just by subtraction.

That's where the `y - mean(y)` comes from.

Pretty much *any* DC removal technique boils down to implicitly or explicitly calculating the DC component, and subtracting it out.  Whether you're using Matlab, real computer code, or a capacitor and a resistor, it's all doing the same thing.